# Mail требует пароль приложения, даже когда я его использую

Tags: python, email, smtp, mail.ru

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(email_string, 'plain'))
#create server
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.ru", 465)
server.starttls()
# Login Credentials for sending the mail
server.login(msg['From'], password)
# send the message via the server.
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], email_string)
server.quit()
```

вот часть кода в msg['from'] передается почта, а в переменную password пароль приложения полученный в mail. Но при запуске выходит ошибка

> NEOBHODIM parol prilozheniya
> https://help.mail.ru/mail/security/protection/external / Application
> password is REQUIRED
> Создание нового пароля приложения не помогает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была такая ошибка, после действий пропало:

0. В настройках почтового аккаунта mail.ru в меню "Пароли для внешних приложений" я сделал пароль для работы с python
1. код использовал такой

   > ```
   > msc_mail_server = 'smtp.mail.ru'
   > msc_from_address = 'user@mail.ru'
   > msc_login_user = 'user'
   > msc_login_pass = 'pass'
   > smtp_link = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(msc_mail_server)
   > smtp_link.login(msc_login_user, msc_login_pass)
   > smtp_link.send_message(msg, msc_from_address, msc_to_address)
   > smtp_link.quit()
   > ```

Comment: новая проблема 
('str' object has no attribute 'get_all')

Comment: Ну это уже не почтовая проблема. Смотри что формируешь в данных для отправки.

Comment: ну так то ошибка поменялась, можно засчитать